# Getting error: 'zip END header not found' when attempting to create a .exe

Tags: jar, exe, launch4j

This is NOT an error relating to any IDE. I've already generated a JAR file, created a build artifact and set up it's run configuration; and I can launch and run the JAR directly just fine on my machine. What I'm attempting to do now is wrap this JAR as an EXE so it can be run on other client machines. I'm trying to use a well-known third-party to do this (Launch4j), but am running into issues. Chiefly, when I go to select the 'Main Class' under 'classpath', it doesn't allow me to select my application's main class and gives a warning: "zip END header not found". I have no clue what this means and can't find anything about it anywhere (other responses relating to this error being encountered while executing the program from within the IDE make no sense and don't match my situation). Why am I getting this error in Launch4j, and how do I fix it?